# android: read Midi tracks info?

Tags: android

*Does anybody know a android MIDI parser that will show a MIDI tracks info?* 
because midi file have many track to become a midi file.I open midi file by cakewalk.it show all tracks(melody,bass..etc).i want android app can show the midi track info.

i try the http://code.google.com/p/android-midi-lib/ by LeffelMania.it can read midi file and you can manipulate it,finally can create an new midi you want.

Answer (score 7):

@sam

To Parse MIDI file please checkout below Java lib...

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/package-summary.html

Also here is one solution suggested to parse MIDI files, they also shown JAVA's MIDI Lib, check followed link below...
http://nettoyeur.noisepages.com/2011/06/glutton-for-punishment-or-how-to-parse-midi-files-with-android/

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/82e98a8dccec/src/share/classes/javax/sound/midi/

Comment: thx for give those suggested solution,it would be a big help.